# Recreate yarn.lock as of a previous date

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

If no `yarn.lock` is present and `yarn install` is executed, a fresh `yarn.lock` is created using the *latest currently available versions* of all dependencies (that are compatible with the versions noted in `package.json`).

Is there a way to re-create the `yarn.lock` that would have been produced at a certain point back in time?

**An example:** Let's say `package.json` has only one dependency [fig-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fig-components?activeTab=versions):

```json
{
  "name": "test",    
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "fig-components": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

This dependency has been [updated frequently](https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/fig-components) during the last 30 days:

```json
{
    "created": "2023-12-05T15:53:53.991Z",
    "1.0.0": "2023-12-05T15:53:54.330Z",
    "1.0.1": "2023-12-06T16:04:37.170Z",
    "1.0.2": "2023-12-24T12:37:30.628Z",
    "1.0.3": "2023-12-24T12:53:59.037Z",
    "1.0.4": "2023-12-25T14:15:10.609Z",
    "1.0.5": "2023-12-30T02:32:15.320Z",
    "1.0.6": "2023-12-30T06:26:59.997Z",
    "1.0.7": "2024-01-03T15:18:26.959Z",
    "1.0.8": "2024-01-04T16:03:12.958Z"
}
```

If I had created my `yarn.lock` on 2023-12-31 I would have gotten version 1.0.6 in the lock file. If I create the file today (2024-01-04) I get version 1.0.8. This is the expected behavior.

Is there a way to create the `yarn.lock` today but with only the versions that were available on 2023-12-31?

**Why would I want to do that?** I want to reproduce a bug that occurred previously but is now no longer reproducible. The former `yarn.lock` [has not been committed to a repo](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/qa#should-lockfiles-be-committed-to-the-repository). I want to avoid to look up and set all versions manually in a large project for the earlier date when the bug was seen.

Comment: ...no, as far as I know not possible. This is why the [official guidance is to commit the lock file to source control](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarn-lock/#toc-check-into-source-control).

Comment: Use Version Ranges in package.json ,  "dependencies": {
  "fig-components": "1.0.6"
}
   and try to Utilize Time-Based Versioning Features : npm install fig-components@1.0.6

Comment: A proxy that removes newer versions from the package information response might be the easiest way to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use a proxy that removes newer version from the package information response

Following the [idea by Ry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77761172/recreate-yarn-lock-as-of-a-previous-date#comment137090361_77761172) a [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) with an [addon](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-examples/) removes all package information from the [metadata sent by the registry](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/responses/package-metadata.md) for packages that have been created after a fixed date.

#### 1. The mitm addon

The addon ensures that the registry will always send the [long version](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/responses/package-metadata.md#full-metadata-format) of the package metadata that contains the `time` property. Then it filters out all versions from the response that have been created after `maxdate`.

```python
from mitmproxy import http
import json 

def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow):
    # yarn will send the type 'application/vnd.npm.install-v1+json' 
    # that does not contain the 'time' information
    flow.request.headers["Accept"] = "application/json"

def response(flow: http.HTTPFlow):
    assert flow.response

    if flow.response.headers["Content-Type"] == "application/json":
        pkg = json.loads(flow.response.content)
                
        # only load versions before maxdate
        maxdate = '2023-06-30T06:26:59.997Z' 

        # get all versions that have been created after maxdate (ignoring timezones...)
        versions_to_delete = {v for (v,t) in pkg['time'].items() if t >= maxdate } 

        # delete the versions that are too new
        for v in versions_to_delete:
            if v in pkg['versions'].keys():
                del pkg['versions'][v]

        # delete the the time information
        del pkg['time']

        # update the information about the latest version
        pkg['dist-tags']['latest'] = max(pkg['versions'].keys())

        flow.response.text = json.dumps(pkg)
```

#### 2. Start the mitm proxy

Using the docker version of mitm and supply the addon code as a volume.

```bash
docker run --rm -it -p 1234:8080 --name mitm \
  -v ./plugin.py:/tmp/plugin.py \
  mitmproxy/mitmproxy mitmproxy -s /tmp/plugin.py
```

#### 3. Yarn configuration

Tell yarn to use use the proxy on port 1234. As the proxy uses its own SSL certificate tell yarn also to accecpt unsecure SSL connections (this could be fixed by [providing a valid SSL certificate to the proxy](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/)).

`.yarnrc` should include the entries

```bash
strict-ssl false
https-proxy "http://localhost:1234"
```

##### 4. Start yarn

Start yarn with a standard `yarn install`. The requests will soon be visible inside of the proxy's screen and newer packages than `maxdate` will be ignored.

**Remarks**:

- this approach has been tested with Yarn version 1.22.19 and mitmproxy version 10.2.1
- this is meant for debugging purposes (the SSL configuration of the proxy and the date comparison inside of the addon need improvements)
- the build process (or at least the part where the packages are loaded) takes longer than usual due to the additional processing inside of mitmproxy